# Hashmap: can get only last value

Tags: java

I'm putting some arrays into hashmap with 2 keys. Then I'm trying to extract these values, but can get values only for last keys. For any another keys I'm getting null pointer exception:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No xyValues
>   for the keys: 'L', '18.2'     at
>   tmp.DataScan1.getSerie(DataScan1.java:49)     at
>   tmp.DataScan1.main(DataScan1.java:66)"

What's wrong?

Here is my working example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class DataScan1 extends HashMap<Character, DataSerie>{
    public static double[] freqs;

    public void putSerie(char lriv, double freq, double[][] xyValues){

        char key1 = lriv;
        long key2 = double2key(round(freq, 4));

        DataSerie dataSerie = new DataSerie();

        dataSerie.put(key2, xyValues);
        this.put(key1, dataSerie);

    }

    private static long double2key(double value){
        long result = (long) (value * 10000);
        return result;      
    }

    public DataScan1(){

        freqs = new double[]{1, 16.9,4.0,18.2,17.4};

        for (int idxfreq=0; idxfreq<freqs.length; idxfreq++){

            double[][] array = new double[][]{{1, 2}, {3,4}};
            putSerie('L', freqs[idxfreq], array);

        }

    }

    public double[][] getSerie(char lriv, double freq){

        char key1 = lriv;
        long key2 = double2key(round(freq, 4));


            double[][] xyValues = this.get(key1).get(key2);
            if (xyValues == null){
                throw new RuntimeException("No xyValues for the keys: '" + lriv + "', '" + freq + "'");
            }
            return xyValues;

    }

    public static void printArr(double[] arr){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }

public static double round(double d, int decimalPlace) {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(d));
        bd = bd.setScale(decimalPlace, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        return bd.doubleValue();
    }




public static void main(String[] args) {
    DataScan1 myData = new DataScan1();
    printArr(myData.freqs);
    double[][] qq = myData.getSerie('L', 17.4); // that serie exist
    double[][] qqq = myData.getSerie('L', 18.2); // but this -- isn't, error here

}

}
```

UPDATE:
I forgot DataSerie definition:

```
public class DataSerie extends HashMap<Long, double[][]>{

}
```

Comment: What is DataSerie ?

Comment: Well, you do override your DataScan1 Entries every time without checking if something with that key already exists `this.put(key1, dataSerie);` <- Here you simple put a new entry with key1='L' into your map every time. You never added any logic to check if entries with that key already exists in your putSerie method.

Comment: Your array `xyValues` in `getSerie()` isn't initialized: `xyValues = new double[][]`.

Comment: You dont show the DataSeries#put method, but if it is directly a HashMap you need to do this.get(key1) first, if it returns something add the values, otherwise put a new DataSerie.

Comment: I don't think extending HashMap is such a good idea here. But that's just a side note.

Comment: Update: I reworked my answer one more time; now it also contains the explanation why your code does what it does.

Comment: Beyond that: please understand that your *coding style* alone makes this program 10 times harder to read than it ought to be! Alone the fact that your classes are **extending** HashMap for absolutely no reason is confusing. As said: I suggest you step back and really read how Java Maps work. Because your code is "works as designed!" And beyond that: you already have print statements **after** adding the values. Simply add more print statements (for example within `putSerie()` and you will see what happens).

Comment: Okay. Seems to be I need to learn. Thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply spoken: **bad** idea.

You want to use a **floating point** value as key for a Map. That means that Double objects will be created; and compared using their equals() methods.

And the thing is: you don't do that. When you compare two floating point numbers, you always always always do something along the lines of (x1 - x2) < epsilon. (see [here](http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-questions-are-endless-on-stackoverflow-com/) for more examples why that is a bad idea; and then [here](http://floating-point-gui.de/languages/java/) for some alternatives; and finally [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713673/precision-error-with-floats-in-java) for some explanations; esp. answer no. 2 by Bernd)

In other words: if you really want to use those numbers as key, then keep them represented as strings!

And beyond that: avoid mixing concepts - you decided to use Maps; so don't make things more complicated by using arrays, too. I would rather define a "Matrix" class to hold the content that is currently in your double[][] array.

Finally, for your **real** problem with the current code:

```
this.put(key1, dataSerie);
```

Here you putting the new dataSerie object into your map. If you look closely, you will find that you keep using the **same** key (the char 'L') all the time. In other words: yes, your code creates a new dataSerie object; but then you are overwriting the **one** and only entry in your map with that value.

Thus, there are **two** ways to go:

1. In case that this map key is **always** the **same** character; well, then you **do not need** to use a map here. Then you would be using a List and just add your values!
2. If your program actually has to deal with different keys, then you might better use a `Map<Char, List<double[][]>>` for example.

But honestly; I think the **real** take away here is: step back, and work your way through [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) in order to **really** understand the things you intend to use!

---

Comment: I guess as long as you just use the same constants as keys nothing bad will actually happen to you. If you start doing calculations and use their results however, the comparison will definitely not work anymore.

Comment: @MaximilianKöstler Sure; but when one is using constant values all over the place, there would not be much need for using a map anyway ...

Comment: @GhostCat you are right, it is a bit of a weird use case to use constant floats as map keys :)

Comment: I did the second update: firstly I'm rounding floating point to some digits and then translating floating point to long. Is this bad?

Comment: @AndreiSh That should work, and see my lastest update for the "real" problem with your code.

Comment: Should I use _unique_ first key? Or can I avoid using unique first key?

Comment: Same character 'L' is example only. It can be different. 'R', 'I', 'V'.

Comment: My character key can be the same(as above) and can be different. Does the map(instead hashmap) needs _unique_ key?

Comment: You can look at my corresponding [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40875807/in-which-object-store-my-data/)

Comment: I told you: please read what Maps **really** do. In your **example**, you are only keeping **one** entry in your DataScan1 class! In other words: when you add the data for 17.4; you **overwrite** the single entry for L that existed before (18.4). When you do map.put(x, y) and map.put(x, z) then map.get(x) returns z; and nothing else. That is what maps do!

Comment: I understood about overwriting. I'm thinking how can I solve the problem...

Comment: In this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40875807/in-which-object-store-my-data/) I explained what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I already told you: if you dont want to overwrite, then you need a `Map<X, List<Y>>` and you have to write code that creates such a list; and instead of just putting key, value; you first have to A) check if there is already a list of values (if not you create an empty list); then you put the value into that list; and then you push *the list* into your map.

Answer (score 1):

In `putSerie()` you always create a new `DataSerie` and replace the old one at key `'L'`

Instead, you should only create a new `DataSerie` there if none exists for key `'L'`. If it does already exist, just take the existing one and insert your new element (`xyValues`) into it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void putSerie(char lriv, double freq, double[][] xyValues){

    char key1 = lriv;
    long key2 = double2key(freq);

    DataSerie dataSerie;
    if (!this.containsKey(key1)) {
        // Only create a new one, when necessary
        dataSerie = new DataSerie();
        this.put(key1, dataSerie);
    } else {
        dataSerie = this.get(key1);
    }

    dataSerie.put(key2, xyValues);
}
```